# querying table inside a table in kdb

Tags: kdb

fellow `q` mortals!

I am stuck on a pretty unusual problem in kdbq+. Essentially I have a table that has a column of tables.

Below is the main table called `full_tab`

```
time                          bmm                                                                                                                                                                                                              $
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------$
2020.08.12D00:06:12.049002000 +`offerid`source_id`sub1`impc`question_id`offer`total_click`rpc`revenue`rpm!(789 128 3 149 111 523 1037 852f;70995 70995 70995 70995 70995 70995 70995 70995f;31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31f;1 2 21 1 0N 0N 0N 0N;956 6$
2020.08.12D00:10:48.186445000 +`offerid`source_id`sub1`impc`question_id`offer`total_click`rpc`revenue`rpm!(789 128 3 149 111 523 1037 852f;70995 70995 70995 70995 70995 70995 70995 70995f;31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31f;3 7 55 5 0N 0N 0N 0N;956 6$
2020.08.12D00:15:50.596247000 +`offerid`source_id`sub1`impc`question_id`offer`total_click`rpc`revenue`rpm!(789 128 3 149 111 523 1037 852f;70995 70995 70995 70995 70995 70995 70995 70995f;31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31f;4 10 81 5 0N 0N 0N 0N;956 $
...
```

each row in `bmm` column is a table that looks like below

```
offerid source_id sub1 impc question_id offer                                           total_click rpc    revenue rpm
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
789     70995     31   1    956         "aaaa"                                          1           0      0       0
128     70995     31   2    698         "bbb"                                           2           0.4    0.8     400
3       70995     31   21   818         "ccc"                                           10          1.0575 10.575  503.5714
149     70995     31   1    941         "ddd"                                           1           0.4    0.4     400
111     70995     31                    "eee"                                           10          1.057  10.575
523     70995     31                    "fff"                                           1           0.4    0.4
1037    70995     31                    "ggg"                                           1           0.4    0.4
852     70995     31                    "hhh"                                           1           0.4    0.4
```

what I want is a final table that looks like below. From the `full_tab` I am trying to extract `time` column and from the corresponding `bmm` row extract the `` bmm[;`rpm] `` value that corresponds to a particular `` bmm[;`question_id] ``, for the case below its `question_id = 818`

```
time                               q818
---------------------------------------------
2020.08.12D00:06:12.049002000      503.5714
2020.08.12D00:10:48.186445000      510.665
2020.08.12D00:15:50.596247000      533.445
...
```

I tried to pull the using the statement below

```
select time, q818: first each  bmm[;`rpm][;(where each bmm[;`question_id]=818)] from full_tab;
```

but the above doesnt seem to work! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use something like the below:

```
    q)getQID:{[t;qid] select time,q818:{[t;qid]exec rpm from t where question_id=qid}[;qid]'[bbm] from t}

    q)getQID[full_tab;818]
    time                          q818
    -------------------------------------
    2014.08.30D03:40:50.876084992 503.75
    2008.06.26D08:14:03.717355744 510.665
```